# variable execution time for a loop using AVX2 instructions

Tags: c, cpu

I want to convert a float buffer into an int8 buffer using AVX2 instructions.

When I measure the time around my conversion function, I can see that it's very stable but from time to time one measure is really higher than the other.

Here is my code

```c
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

static __m64 func (const __m256* coef_8xFP32_,
            float** input_1xFP32_ptr_)
{
    __m256   input_8xFP32 = {};
    __m256   coeffed_8xFP32 = {};
    __m256i  convert_8xINT32;
    __m128i* convertLow_4xINT8_ptr = nullptr;
    __m128i* convertHigh_4xINT8_ptr = nullptr;
    __m128i  packed_8xINT16 = {};
    __m64*   packedLow_8xINT8_ptr = nullptr;
    __m64*   packedHigh_8xINT8_ptr = nullptr;
    __m64    packed_8xINT8 = {};

    // init 8xFP32 with input data
    input_8xFP32 = _mm256_set_ps((*input_1xFP32_ptr_)[7], (*input_1xFP32_ptr_)[6], (*input_1xFP32_ptr_)[5], (*input_1xFP32_ptr_)[4],
                                 (*input_1xFP32_ptr_)[3], (*input_1xFP32_ptr_)[2], (*input_1xFP32_ptr_)[1], (*input_1xFP32_ptr_)[0]);

    (*input_1xFP32_ptr_) += 8;

    // multiple 8xFP32 per coef
    coeffed_8xFP32 = _mm256_mul_ps(input_8xFP32, *coef_8xFP32_);

    // convert 8xFP32 into 8xINT32
    convert_8xINT32 = _mm256_cvtps_epi32 (coeffed_8xFP32);

    // pack 8xINT32 into 8xINT16
    convertLow_4xINT8_ptr  = (__m128i*)&convert_8xINT32;
    convertHigh_4xINT8_ptr = (__m128i*)&convert_8xINT32 + 1;
    packed_8xINT16 = _mm_packs_epi32 (*convertLow_4xINT8_ptr, *convertHigh_4xINT8_ptr);

    // pack 8xINT16 into 8xINT8
    packedLow_8xINT8_ptr  = (__m64*)&packed_8xINT16;
    packedHigh_8xINT8_ptr = (__m64*)&packed_8xINT16 + 1;
    packed_8xINT8 = _mm_packs_pi16 (*packedLow_8xINT8_ptr, *packedHigh_8xINT8_ptr);

    return (packed_8xINT8);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const int bufferSize = 8 * 10000;
    float input[bufferSize] = {};
    int8_t output[bufferSize] = {};
    float coef = 1.;

    const int statSize = 1000;
    struct timespec start;
    struct timespec end;
    double val[statSize] = {};
    double min = 1;
    double max = 0;
    double accu = 0;
    double mean = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < statSize; i++)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        for (int j = 0; j < bufferSize; j += 1)
            input[j] = (rand() % 2560) / 10. - 128;

        __m256 coef_8xFP32 = _mm256_set1_ps(coef);
        float* input_1xFP32_ptr = (float*)input;
        __m64* output_ptr_8xINT8 = (__m64*)output;

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);

        for (int j = 0; j < bufferSize; j += 8)
        {
            *output_ptr_8xINT8 = func (&coef_8xFP32, &input_1xFP32_ptr);
            ++output_ptr_8xINT8;
        }

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);

        val[i] = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) / 1e-3 + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1e6;
        if (val[i] > max)
            max = val[i];
        if (val[i] < min)
            min = val[i];
        accu += val[i];
    }

//  for (int j = 0; j < bufferSize; j += 1)
//      printf ("%d %.3f %d\n", j, input[j], output[j]);

    mean = accu / statSize;
    for (int i = 0; i < statSize; i++)
        if (val[i] > ((max - mean) / 2 + mean))
            printf ("%3d %f\n", i, val[i]);

    printf ("min   %f\n", min);
    printf ("max   %f\n", max);
    printf ("mean  %f\n", mean);
    printf ("DELTA %f\n", max / mean);

    return (0);
}
```

And the compilation commands

```sh
g++ -Wall -Werror -O3 -std=c++11 -mavx2 -c floatToInt8.cpp -o floatToInt8.o 
g++ floatToInt8.o -o floatToInt8
```

I expected the min, max and mean values to be very similar.
Here are my results (I tried on several Linux hosts, I've got similar results):

```
  0 0.060360
 34 0.068733
 92 0.067925
369 0.058768
565 0.059178
604 0.055466
621 0.065434
635 0.068510
min   0.036119
max   0.068733
mean  0.040500
DELTA 1.697113
```

How can be explained those few too high values ?

Comment: There are lots of potential ways this can happen.  Some are:  Your OS is running more than just your program.  If the OS changes the execution unit (CPU core) that your process is running on there can be additional latency when the caches in the new core are loaded.  CPU throttling can slow the CPU, causing more real time to pass.

Comment: Could be the CPU changing power states. I've previously seen (on Nahalem architectures) 300ms delays where the CPU switches power states once it realises a heavy workload has started and is going on for a good long while. During this time the entire machine was paused - ftrace data showed literally everything in the OS stopped stone dead for this time.